# Strapi - How can I upload files and create new model entry at the same time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, file-upload, strapi

In my app, I wish to do just like in the admin panel. I have a form that have other datas + files and I want to create everything at once. How can I do that if I don't know the RefID since the new entry is not yet created. I have tried alot of things and so far nothing works. Here is code example :

Form :

```
 jobsForm = this.fb.group({
    nom: [null],
    date: [null],
    address_chargement: [null],
    address_dechargement: [null],
    client: [null],
    completed: [false],
    status: ['waiting'],
    comment_user: [null],
    comment_admin: [null],
    files: [null],
});
```

Form is dispatched to NGRX Store create action which call my service as follow :

```
public createJob = (payload: IJob): Observable<IJob>  => {
    const data = new FormData();
    Object.entries(payload).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        data.append(key, value);
    });
    return this.http.post<IJob>(`${this.env.backendUrl}/jobs`, data);
}
```

I get errors such as :

```
[2019-06-16T20:10:03.573Z] error Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table jobs has no column named fields
```

Or it just does not upload.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible to do that.

By default it's not, you will have to do some updates in your controllers / services.

The content manager have this ability to manage entry creation and file upload in the same request. So let's copy this logic in your create action.

Note: you will have to send the request with a `FormData` - was not this type of request before.

Here is the controller function that create entry https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-content-manager/controllers/ContentManager.js#L61

Here is the service function that create and upload the files https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-content-manager/services/ContentManager.js#L63

First you will have to create a new service function named `addAndUpload`.

```
async addAndUpload(ctx) {
  // Get form data
  let values = ctx.request.body;

  // Silent recursive parser.
  const parser = value => {
    try {
      value = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
      // Silent.
    }

    return _.isArray(value) ? value.map(obj => parser(obj)) : value;
  };

  // Get files
  const files = values.files;

  // Get entry data
  values = Object.keys(values.fields).reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current] = parser(values.fields[current]);

    return acc;
  }, {});

  // Create the entry without files
  const entry = await strapi.api.job.services.add(values)

  // Then, request plugin upload.
  if (Object.keys(files).length > 0) {
    // Upload new files and attach them to this entity.
    // Here `job` have to be the model name
    await strapi.plugins.upload.services.upload.uploadToEntity(
      {
        id: entry.id || entry._id,
        model: 'job',
      },
      files
    );
  }

  return strapi.api.job.services.job.findOne({
    id: entry.id || entry._id,
  });
}
```

And in your `create` controller function your will have to call `strapi.api.job.services.addAndUpload(ctx)` instead of the `add` function.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had hoped not to write anything custom in Strapi (which is why I chose to use it ). I took another direction inside my job form component, on file select I append the files to a new FormData and send them straight to upload. In return I get all the uploaded files with the IDs etc, which I add to my form on submit to create the reference to the images in the new job. I have an array that tracks the added files so I can delete them from the form and the server. Also destroy all uploaded files in ngOnDestroy if form is aborted.

Comment: Okay! It's an other way to manage this. Anyway it's a good ressource to keep in mind if t's needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think itsn't possible make like that. I suggest break create `Job` proccess to two steps:

1. Create `File` -> `POST /upload`.
2. Create `Job` with `id` from `FileResponse` -> `POST /job`.

SQLITE_ERROR inform you that `Job` model doesn't have `fields`, becouse `Job` models accepts `refId` to `File`.

You can use `switchMap` to merge two Observable.

[File Upload](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/upload.html#usage)